# Ordenar lista en python, unos valores en ascendente y otros en descendente

Tags: python, lista, ordenar, ascendente

Tengo un dataframe "results" con valores, tal que así

```
      Symbol      Close      MACD  MACD signal  MACD_CrossUp  MACD_CrossDown  diffMACD          K  ...    diffKDJ  KDJ_buy  KDJ_sell  Kalman  Choppy  Long  Short  Tick
0  STMX/USDT    0.00966 -0.000024    -0.000044          True           False  0.000020  77.608368  ...  50.460498     True     False    True   56.28  True  False  STMX
1  DYDX/USDT    1.66200  0.002000     0.000198          True           False  0.001802  73.642217  ...  24.518652     True     False    True   59.22  True  False  DYDX
2  HBAR/USDT    0.08807  0.000033    -0.000138          True           False  0.000171  82.441072  ...  23.431535     True     False    True   48.73  True  False  HBAR
3   FLM/USDT    0.11750  0.000126    -0.000468          True           False  0.000594  66.179365  ...  21.874289     True     False    True   59.20  True  False   FLM
4   RVN/USDT    0.02738 -0.000009    -0.000033          True           False  0.000023  72.490969  ...  17.821932     True     False    True   65.48  True  False   RVN
5   BNX/USDT  131.14000 -0.002547    -0.163706          True           False  0.161159  83.749361  ...  16.006878     True     False    True   62.13  True  False   BNX
6   XMR/USDT  186.96000  0.371050     0.203506          True           False  0.167544  79.540010  ...  14.986170     True     False    True   57.52  True  False   XMR
7   XEM/USDT    0.05010  0.000006    -0.000056          True           False  0.000063  67.637342  ...  14.427833     True     False    True   59.89  True  False   XEM
8   XTZ/USDT    2.11000  0.006027     0.003346          True           False  0.002681  85.457781  ...  13.049522     True     False    True   55.48  True  False   XTZ
9   RLC/USDT    0.90310  0.002712    -0.000123          True           False  0.002835  89.556189  ...   8.648385     True     False    True   38.42  True  False   RLC
```

La idea que necesito solucionar es que ordene sobre varios campos pero necesito en unos casos que sean en ascendente y otros en descendente.

Ahora mismo tengo estas dos ordenaciones:

```
df_top = results.sort_values(   ['Long',    'diffKDJ', 'diffMACD', 'Choppy'],ascending=False)
df_bottom = results.sort_values(   ['Short',    'diffKDJ', 'diffMACD', 'Choppy'],ascending=False)
```

Por tanto mis resultados salen ordenados ubicando, primero, todos los Long, y de entre ellos, los que tengan "diffKDJ" más elevado, y si coincidieran algunos valores, los reordenaría por "diffMACD" y mismo caso para "choppy".

Pero y si necesito que realice esto?

- Primero agrupar todos los "Long" = True (Esta ordenación ya se hace bien con el df_top = results.sort_values()
- Ahora que ya tengo ordenados todos los "Long" = TRUE, quiero que estos mismos registros me salgan ordenados por el campo "diffMACD", poniendo primero el que sea más cercano a 0, o sea, ordenando en ASCENDENTE
- Y en el supuesto caso que hubiera dos o más registros cuy "diffMACD" sea idéntico, en este caso habría que ordenar por "diffKDJ" también en ASCENDENTE

Como ejemplo, pongo el de arriba de cómo quisiera que saliera. Dejo los índices como el de arriba para que sea más fácil ver la reordenación

```
      Symbol      Close      MACD  MACD signal  MACD_CrossUp  MACD_CrossDown  diffMACD          K  ...    diffKDJ  KDJ_buy  KDJ_sell  Kalman  Choppy  Long  Short  Tick
0  STMX/USDT    0.00966 -0.000024    -0.000044          True           False  0.000020  77.608368  ...  50.460498     True     False    True   56.28  True  False  STMX
4   RVN/USDT    0.02738 -0.000009    -0.000033          True           False  0.000023  72.490969  ...  17.821932     True     False    True   65.48  True  False   RVN
7   XEM/USDT    0.05010  0.000006    -0.000056          True           False  0.000063  67.637342  ...  14.427833     True     False    True   59.89  True  False   XEM
2  HBAR/USDT    0.08807  0.000033    -0.000138          True           False  0.000171  82.441072  ...  23.431535     True     False    True   48.73  True  False  HBAR
3   FLM/USDT    0.11750  0.000126    -0.000468          True           False  0.000594  66.179365  ...  21.874289     True     False    True   59.20  True  False   FLM
1  DYDX/USDT    1.66200  0.002000     0.000198          True           False  0.001802  73.642217  ...  24.518652     True     False    True   59.22  True  False  DYDX
8   XTZ/USDT    2.11000  0.006027     0.003346          True           False  0.002681  85.457781  ...  13.049522     True     False    True   55.48  True  False   XTZ
9   RLC/USDT    0.90310  0.002712    -0.000123          True           False  0.002835  89.556189  ...   8.648385     True     False    True   38.42  True  False   RLC
5   BNX/USDT  131.14000 -0.002547    -0.163706          True           False  0.161159  83.749361  ...  16.006878     True     False    True   62.13  True  False   BNX
6   XMR/USDT  186.96000  0.371050     0.203506          True           False  0.167544  79.540010  ...  14.986170     True     False    True   57.52  True  False   XMR
```

Comment: Buen día, disculpa, no se entiende bien lo que deseas hacer, ¿Podrías explicarlo con más detalles y agregar un ejemplo de lo que esperarías obtener?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato he modificado la pregunta para intentar ser más concisa y he puesto el ejemplo reordenado

Comment: Gracias, es decir, deseas combinar algunas columnas con orden ascendente y otras con descendente, ¿Es correcto? Eso es muy fácil, el argumento `ascending` puede recibir una lista, por lo que podrías poner `[False, True, True]` por decir algo, los índices de la lista corresponden a las columnas que has indicado

Comment: Pues ha resultado ser así. Pon si quieres una respuesta para que te la valide. Mil gracias @HeytalePazguato

Comment: No hace falta redactar una respuesta por algo pequeño, yo creo que hizo falta leer un poco la documentación. Lo bueno es que quedó resuelto. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En base a la respuesta de @HeytalePazguato:

Resuelto así:

```
df_top = results.sort_values(   ['Long',    'diffKDJ', 'diffMACD', 'Choppy'],ascending=[False, True, True, False])
df_bottom = results.sort_values(['Short',   'diffKDJ', 'diffMACD', 'Choppy'],ascending=[False, True, True, False])
```

El argumento ascending puede recibir una lista, por lo que podrías poner **[False, True, True]**